# Custom Picasso with Builder leaks NetworkBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, memory-leaks, picasso

I am using a custom `Picasso` instance with `Picasso.Builder()` to provide my own `RequestHandler` in adapter like so:

```
private Picasso mPicasso;

public Adapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;

    mPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext)
            .addRequestHandler(new RequestHandler() {
            ...
            })
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    mPicasso.load(...)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(...)
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

But everytime Activity recreats (for example through a configuration change), `com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher$NetworkBroadcastReceiver` instance inside `mPicasso` leaks and never get's garbage collected from memory.

Here's the chart from Eclipse Memory Analyzer:
http://www.upsara.com/images/q93m_chart49.png

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by calling shutdown from the callback methods:

```
mPicasso.load(...)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(...)
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        mPicasso.shutdown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        mPicasso.shutdown();
                    }
                });
```